# c# BitmapImage Width and Height equal 1

Tags: width, bitmapimage

Can someone help me with BitmapImage use?

I use BitmapImage in a wpf project. When I set the wpf project is startup project, and run it the code works fine but when I start the wpf exe from a winform project code, the bitmapimage's width and height is 1.

The code example is as follows:

```
 public  async Task Open(string path)
        {

        string strpath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +  path;

        strpath = @"F:\test\Meteorology\Meteorology\bin\Debug\pic\56778.JPG";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(strpath))
        {
            Image = null;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Image");
            IsLoading = true;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoading");

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Image = new BitmapImage();

                Image.BeginInit();
                Image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                Image.UriSource = new Uri(strpath);
                Image.EndInit();
                Image.Freeze();
            });

            if (Math.Abs(Image.Width / Image.Height - 2) > 0.001)
                WarningMessage("Warning", "The opened image is not equirectangular (2:1)! Rendering may be improper.");

            RecentImageManager.AddAndSave(path);

            IsLoading = false; RaisePropertyChanged("IsLoading");
            RaisePropertyChanged("Image");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi,everybody, when the question occur, i find the VS diagnostic tool write a exception message as follow: PresentationCore.dll 中的“System.OutOfMemoryException”, may be it is the reason for the question,How to resove it？thanks

Comment: The rootcause is memery out for the issue,and change the build version to 64 bit to solve it

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't get any exceptions. Was you bitmap displaying? In my case the bitmap is displayed but I don't get proper size.